# Trouble with distinguishing between singulars and plurals

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Recently I have got this sensitivity to choose a singular noun v. plural one. For example, which of the followings are correct:

- Let's make friend with each other.
- Let's make friends with each other.

And

- We are friend.
- We are friends.

Answer (score 2):

You say "Let's make friends," not "Let's make friend." The phrase "make friends" is an idiom, so it may not be easy to pin down the logic behind it.

You also use the plural in "we are friends." But this is the ordinary use of the plural, as in "John and Mary are friends." John and Mary are more than one person, so the plural is used. "We" likewise refers to more than one person.

Comment: Can you show some prove for the idiom part?

Comment: @lonesome - If you google [define "make friends"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+"make+friends") you'll see it defined in many places, and if you look up the usage, you'll see that ["make friends" is very common and "make friend" is almost never used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+friends%2Cmake+friend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20friends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20friend%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @lonesome Please see this entry in the Merriam-Webster dictionary online: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20friends

Comment: I see. but it is not clear that the plural s in make friends is because of the plurality of the object in the example (children) or the subject (people) or something else. Because I did not see anything suggesting it was an idiom in the link that you have provided.